# Syncing git origin/master with upstream/master

Tags: git

I have synced my origin master with upstream/master by fetch, then rebasing.

How do I determine if what I did worked?

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify what you've done, what your remotes look like, git log and anything else about your state. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

run the following

```
git log --oneline upstream/master
git log --oneline master
```

Do you see the same commit from `upstream/master` in the `master`? If so, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

look at the git history; I recommend using a tool called `gitg`.